# Graphical representation of ax+by+cz=n

Tags: geometry

How $ax+by+cz=n$ actually looks like ?

Does it represents particularly any shape ?

Comment: Well, you can see that all the partial derivatives are constants, so it should be a pretty flat shape ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane in 3-space has the equation

$$ax + by + cz = d$$

where at least one of the numbers a, b, c must be nonzero.

It represents a plane which is perpendicular to the vector $a \bf{i} +b\bf{j} +c\bf{k}$ and which passes through the origin.

Consider a point (x,y,z) in real space. If  this point lies on the above plane, the position vector of this point when dotted with the vector $a \bf{i} +b\bf{j} +c\bf{k}$ should be equal to $d$.